# How to script the creation & configuration of a portable (vm-based?) Windows 7 dev environment?

Tags: development-process, development-environment

I'm getting a new computer and would like to minimize the time spent configuring and maintaining dev environments on my various machines.

To that end, I'm thinking that creating a vm with my preferred ide and configuration and using that vm for development on all my machines.

I'd like to use Windows 7 as the vm's os.

For those who have tried or currently use an approach like this,

1. How can I keep the disk image synchronized without resorting to a thumb drive? What are pros/cons (if any).
2. As I do this first configuration manually, should I record my steps in the interest of scripting them later?
3. If so, what approach would you recommend for scripting? Cygwin + bash? Ant? Something else? Why?
4. Are there potential difficulties I should be aware of re: sharing a filesystem? For instance, in A) accessing vm files from the host machine or B) accessing the vm's HTTP server from the host machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [At what point should I have my Windows developers upgrade to the latest release of Windows?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132505/at-what-point-should-i-have-my-windows-developers-upgrade-to-the-latest-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently use [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) for the same thing, but with linux boxes and many people use it this way. You might want to "package" a windows base box. I've never tried with windows so do not know how.

Comment: I'm checking it out now but I'm also considering http://clonezilla.org/ (for anyone else who finds that useful)

Comment: Also, this: http://www.fogproject.org